# Leaderboard position SQL

Tags: mysql, leaderboard

He there,

I've found a lot of questions like this one, but I cannot seem to work it out. So I'm gonna ask it and hope that someone can help me with this specific problem (or direct me to the question if it is a duplicate).

I have the following three tables in my database:

**tbl_achievements**

```
id | points
```

**tbl_achievements_finished**

```
id | user_id | achievement_id
```

**tbl_users**

```
id
```

What I would like to do, is select a specific user or list of users and see the positions/ranks. The idea is that all the achievements the user finishes, yield points. The perfect outcome would be something like:

```
rank | user_id | achievement_points
1    | 6       | 65
2    | 3       | 45
3    | 2       | 15
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I hope there is someone out there that can help me out with (an idea for) a query.

Thanks a lot! If anything is unclear, please let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT af.user_id, SUM(points) as 'achievement_points' 
FROM tbl_users as u
LEFT JOIN tbl_achievements_finished AS af ON u.id = af.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_achievements AS a ON a.id = af.achievement_id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY SUM(points) DESC
```

This is the sample output of the above query:

```
| user_id | achievement_points |
|---------|--------------------|
|       3 |                 40 |
|       1 |                 25 |
|       2 |                 15 |
```

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69775/9/0

I didn't manage to keep the rank in place because of the ordering, but you can always have it when you process the query.